# Forcing specific version of QT in .pro file

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm searching for a way to force a specific version of QT in a .pro file. To be more specific, I'd like to force `qmake` to use only QT 5.x version with my project instead of QT 4.x and QT 5.x

Is there a way to do so?

PS: I'm not asking for a way to stop/halt the compile process (aka check QT version, and if lower than 5.x just throw qFatal/equivalent). I'm looking for a way to actually *choose* which version to use while generating the `Makefile` with `qmake`

Answer (score 7):

You can throw a error if a user is running qmake with a version you do not want him to use. ex:

```
lessThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5): error("requires Qt 5")
```

Answer (score 4):

I really doubt you can do this. `qmake` is a part of framework and goes together with libraries. When you say `Qt of specific verion` you mean only libraries, but it is not correct.

To use specific version of Qt, you actially need to run different version of `qmake`. If you are using QtCreator - you should select it in project's options, if not - type absolute path to file `qmake`. You can find out, which version of Qt `qmake` uses, you can type `qmake --version`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I'm running qmake-qt5 and I'm still getting a Makefile which is using qt4! (I'll triple check this afternoon, just to be sure, but that's the last thing I could see from yesterday's tests)

Comment: That's very strange. Try this: 1. Open terminal in your project directory. 2. Run `qmake-qt5 --version` to make sure, you're using the correct version of Qt. 3. Run `qmake-qt5 && make clean && make` 4. Go to your app and check the dependencies (`ldd` command in linux).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/j2m5jLCM here's a log running what you asked. It does use qt4 with qmake-qt5. Really weird.

Answer (score 1):

As Amartel wrote in his answer, you should point to the correct qmake version (check it by typing `qmake --version` in the console)

It might be that your project has been generated using the wrong qmake executable and some files are not removed even if you issue a nmake clean or make clean.

Check that there are no Makefile in the source tree after the clean (these files will typically contain the path to the qt version to use, and if not regenerated correctly will point to the wrong Qt version).